# How to fix Samsung Galaxy S3 to boot successfully?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot

I'm using *Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300*. Recently, I installed an app and the problem started. The phone started to crash. I had to restart the phone to work but the problem just repeated. But now, when I want to boot the phone, it just shows me the Samsung animating logo with a blue LED light, but it doesn't boot successfully and stays on showing the logo.

I tried many times to wipe the factory data, but nothing is fixed.

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: if stock rom doesn't boot on factory reset this sounds like emmc wear-out, unrelated to last app installed. try to re-flash stock rom, or maybe install custom rom